# MySQL create ID based on date and field increasing by 1 each instance

Tags: mysql, field

I want to create an ID field in a table where the ID increases by one with each date.  So the ID would be like the below I don't want them to be unique numbers so each team can have ID 1,2,3 etc.  I hope I have explained this well enough.

```
Team         Date         ID
Liverpool    25/01/2016    1
Liverpool    28/02/2016    2
Liverpool    01/03/2016    3
Everton      25/01/2016    1
Everton      28/02/2016    2
```

Comment: What is the ID column good for. If it depends on the Date column, you are violating a normalization rule.

Comment: What it will be used for is to identify the round the fixture belongs in, because games are played over a period of Friday to Monday I am wanting all of these games to be classed as "round 1" then the next time they play a game "round 2" this will make it easier for me to then create views based on the x number of previous rounds.  Hopefully this makes sense calling it an ID is probably wrong it is not really an ID as such as it will not be joined on this.